# Get only updated fields along with identifiers in DynamoDB stream

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Is there a way to get ONLY updated fields in an object along with some other attributes (ie identifiers for that object, be it primary key or whatever)
On amazon documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html
I see we have four flavors: KEYS ONLY, NEW IMAGE, OLD IMAGE, NEW AND OLD IMAGES
The only possible way I can see right now to fetch all updated attributes along with the identifier is using NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES and then cross-checking each attribute in NEW IMAGE vs OLD IMAGE. Is there a better way going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you are hoping for. You could imagine a fifth `StreamViewType` which only stores the key and the updated attributes, but unfortunately DynamoDB Streams does not support it.

Interestingly, though I doubt it helps you, `ReturnValues` does support the mode you were wishing for - see`UPDATED_NEW` in [UpdateItem's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html). But alas it's not supported by DynamoDB streams.

If you are willing to entertain alternatives to DynamoDB, there is the open-source [Scylla Alternator](https://www.scylladb.com/alternator/) which is compatible with DynamoDB and DynamoDB Streams, and its implementation of Streams is based on Scylla's CDC ("change-data capture"), which can natively capture *deltas* exactly like you hoped for. These deltas are not currently exposed in Scylla's DynamoDB Streams-compatible API because it's not  part of that API - but such a feature can be added fairly easily.

Comment: Yea seems as it may not be possible to do via DynamoDB streams. I just will get the JSON DIFF between OLD IMAGE and NEW IMAGE to get the updated values. And thanks for that link, I will be checking that out